# WPF: Set ListViewItem from textblock in the Listview within a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1, datatemplate

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 project with a ListView that has it's itemssource filled from c# code behind.  It works but i end up with empty spaces between single line textblocks.  I've tried setting heights on the textblock, a grid it sits within, the listview itself.  I tried setting an ItemContainerStyle with binding the height to the height of the textblock but it doesn't work.
If I set the text of the TextBlock to the Actual Height binding I get 0 so I must be doing something wrong.  I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the height of the ListViewItems but since they are populated from code I can't figure out how to make them do what I want.  I also tried switching to a ItemsControl for the list but it doesn't seem to scroll and work as well. 
Here is the XAML of the Listview:

```
<ListView x:Name="TheList" IsHoldingEnabled="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding items}"
                      Loaded="WhenListViewBaseLoaded"
                      ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True"
                      IsItemClickEnabled="True">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding ElementName=txtBibleText, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="ItemTemplateGrid" Holding="ListViewItem_Holding" Background="Blue">
                        <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                            <MenuFlyout>
                                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Share"
                                                Click="ShareFlyoutItem_Click" />
                                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Add to Sharing"
                                                Click="AddSharingFlyoutItem_Click" />
                            </MenuFlyout>
                        </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                        <Grid x:Name="gridText">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtBibleText" 
                                   FontSize="{Binding TheFontSize}"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                   Margin="0,0,0,0" FontFamily="Global User Interface">
                            <Run Text="{Binding VerseNumber}"/>
                            <Run Text="{Binding BibleText}"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Code behind that populates the ListView:

```
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load(TranlationFilePath);
            var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("testament").Descendants("book").Descendants("chapter").Descendants("verse")
                       where (string)query.Parent.Parent.Parent.Attribute("name") == GetTestament
                       where (string)query.Parent.Parent.Attribute("name") == GetBibleBook
                       where (string)query.Parent.Attribute("number") == GetChapter
                       select new BibleLoad
                       {
                           VerseNumber = (string)query.Attribute("number"),
                           BibleText = (string)query.Value.ToString(),
                           TheFontSize = FontSize
                       };
            TheList.ItemsSource = data;
```

Thank you for your time.  This is my first time posting a question so hopefully I did it right.  I have searched and searched and experimented for quite awhile.

[image]

After editing the XML and making a record short.
[image: With verse 8 edited]

With turning off the text wrapping.

[image]

With wrapping back on, height set to 20 and minheight set to 31.
[image]

MinHeight to 20 wrapping on:

[image]

Comment: can you post your xml document?

Comment: Do you get spaces regularly after each 5 elements or so?

Comment: The xml document is kinda long because it's the entire Bible but here's the essence of it:
'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bible translation="King James Version">
 <testament name="Old">
  <book name="Genesis">
   <chapter number="1">
    <verse number="1">In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.</verse>
    <verse number="2">And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.</verse>
    <verse.....>
   </chapter>
  </book>
 </testament>
</bible>'

Comment: Can you answer to comment no. 2?

Comment: No, not regurlarly after each 5 elements or so.  It's only when there's a single line of text in a textblock which is a verse of the Bible.  But it's every time there's a single line of text.

Comment: So, from the XML a line like:
<verse number="2">Reuben, Simeon, Levi, and Judah</verse>
or
<verse number="3">Issachar, Zebulun, and Benjamin</verse>
Would produce an empty space because they are shorter verses.

Comment: OK, try make some changes in XML file to troubleshoot the problem. In <verse number="8"> Change the text to something like ABC and run the program and post the image of output.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to put an image in the comments so I edited the question and added the output there after changing verse 8 to ABC.

Comment: OK, now can you turn off the textWrapping in your XAML?

Comment: Yes, everytime I do that way. Ok. Now can you get rid of ListView.ItemContainerStyle?

Comment: Also add this attribute to TextBlock : `MinHeight="31 or something"`. If that doesn't make a change then try to change Height="SomeValue" and Turn on TextWrapping again.

Comment: It looks identical to the image with no wrapping.  No difference.

Comment: Changing the MinHeight to 31 and setting the wrapping back on made it look like the original output with empty spaces.  Adding a height to the textblock truncates the text of longer verses and still has space between single line verses.

Comment: Now please remove Height, set MinHeight to 20 and TextWrapping="Wrap". I think you should get your desired output.

Comment: Oops!!!! Sorry, set your minHeight="15".

Comment: Nope, same as before with empty spaces after short verses.

Comment: Please try minHeight="15" or less.........

Comment: Same output with minHeight="15" as with 20.

Comment: Go to your C# code put a breakpoint and see the text returned from XML file. Does that contain any extra characters like newline and spaces?

Comment: No, doesn't look like any newline or spaces.  Output from a short verse with extra space.
query = <verse number="5">And Bilhah conceived, and bare Jacob a son.</verse>

Comment: Sorry to say, but I can't find any other issues with your code. It might be coming from styles or anywhere. Still if you can then please create a sample project. Check if the same problem persists? If you have same problem after that, then please post the sample on any website like drive.google.com and share the link of the project here. Whenever I get time, I will try to solve it.

Comment: You may want to try setting the 'Margin' property of the ListViewItem in the ItemContainerStyle - If there's padding on that, it may also mess things up. Also, check the margin property of the datatemplate's root element.

Answer (score 1):

The extra space comes from the ListViewItem template for the ItemContainerStyle. The default template includes space not only for the ItemTemplate but also for adornments such as checkboxes used to mark selection. Note the CheckboxContainers' Rectangle's Height of 25.5 and the SelectedCheckMark's Height of 34.

```
<Grid x:Name="CheckboxContainer">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="CheckboxContainerTranslateTransform" X="{ThemeResource ListViewItemContentOffsetX}"/>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    <Rectangle x:Name="NormalRectangle" Fill="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="25.5" Stroke="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBorderThemeBrush}" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBorderThemeThickness}" Width="25.5"/>
    <Path x:Name="CheckGlyph" Data="M0,123 L39,93 L124,164 L256,18 L295,49 L124,240 z" Fill="{ThemeResource CheckBoxForegroundThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="17" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="2.5" StrokeLineJoin="Round" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="18.5"/>
</Grid>
```

and

```
<Border x:Name="SelectedBorder" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource GridViewItemMultiselectBorderThickness}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0">
    <Grid x:Name="SelectedCheckMark" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="34" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="34">
        <Path x:Name="SelectedEarmark" Data="M0,0 L40,0 L40,40 z" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <Path x:Name="SelectedGlyph" Data="M0,123 L39,93 L124,164 L256,18 L295,49 L124,240 z" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="14.5" Margin="0,1,1,0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="17"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

If you don't need the selection behavior you can strip the ItemContainerStyle to just the pieces you need so it doesn't have to make space for adornments that aren't relevant to your app. If you do need selection you can move or resize the selection checks so they'll fit with your design.

You can generate the default ItemContainerStyle template by selecting your ListView in the designer, right clicking and chosing Edit Additional Templates.Edit Generated Item Container (ItemContainerStyle) Edit a copy... 
[image]

You can then edit down the adornment Heights as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to set minheight or height? try giving a font size and it will adjust the height itself keep the textwrapping=wrap... and another thing why are you setting grid.colum=1? ..you have only 1 column.